# I want to show products by items

Tags: php, codeigniter

Based on the products i want to show the items ,these are retrieved from the database . I have used two foreach loops so products and items are repeating .Below is the code how i used .i dont want to repeat them

```
<?php 
        if($products)
        {
         foreach($products as $products)
         {
             echo $products->productname.'<br/>';
             foreach($itemsbyproducts as $items)
             {
                echo  $items->itemname.'<br/>';
             }
         }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: can you paste data of both array ? your expected o/p unclear

Comment: ($products as $products) that is wrong? did you mean the 's' in the 2nd variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$prod_array = $item_array = array();
if ($products)
{
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        if (!in_array($product->productname, $prod_array))
        {
            echo $product->productname . '<br/>';
            $prod_array[] = $product->productname;
        }
        foreach ($itemsbyproducts as $items)
        {
            if (!in_array($items->itemname, $item_array))
            {
                echo  $items->itemname . '<br/>';
                $item_array[] = $items->itemname;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try this, it will create two temp arrays for products and items, and add each product or item to the corresponding temp array, and then checks on next loop if it has already been added and if not then will echo out.